# Dev-C++ / [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: arrays, c, printf, dev-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int dizi[9];
    int x;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        scanf("%d",&x); 
        dizi[i]=x;
        printf("%d",dizi[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm new here I'm also new for coding, so I think this is very easy problem. What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 10 numbers but the array has space for 9 numbers. Consider which numbers are read, if the upper limit is 10:

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

The upper limit should be equal to the array's size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```